# How should I use django forms for a <select> value that appears often?

Tags: html, django

I'm writing an application that allows a user to interact with a database of information (searching, saving entries, etc).

In the search part of the application, I have multiple fields that we would like to allow the user to be able to specify < <= = >= > for the specific field.  I have a form that I am using as a template for my form

My model (simplified):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)
    SKU = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

My form:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['id','model_name','SKU','price']
```

Now, in our html - we would like for the search parameters of the form to allow for the user to specify less than, less than equal, etc.  So I have the following html:

```
<form class="form-inline has-feedback" id="search_form" method="post" action="{% url 'search' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Search</legend>
                {{item_form.non_field_errors}}                          
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    {{item_form.price.errors}}
                    <label for="{{ item_form.price.id_for_label }}" class="control-label">price:</label>
                    <select name="price_operator">
                        <option value="lt">&#60;</option>
                        <option value="lte">&#60;&#61;</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="e">&#61;</option>
                        <option value="gte">&#62;&#61;</option>
                        <option value="gt">&#62;</option>
                    </select>
                    {% render_field item_form.price placeholder="price" class+="form-control input-group-md" %}
                </div>
                ... etc
```

How I was intending to use this is to have it simply grab the "price_operator" doing something like

```
oper = request.POST.get['price_operator']
```

then do some logic to get the right operator.

My question is:

A) will the above work?  I have not used select tags thus far and am not sure if that's how you access them.

B) There are quite a few more fields than I displayed in the model (cut it down to be more concise) and there will be many instances where I need to add the same operator dropdown.  Would it be more efficient to instead add a field in my ItemForm (or rather multiple fields as I imagine each field that requires it will require their own operator field) and let django do the validation?

C) If this is better, how exactly would I go about getting the same results that I currently have except with the form method?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as far as I can tell. If you want to save on code you could save the dropdown in another HTML file and use the [include template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include). I don't think it's too important that you add it to ItemForm.